# splash text is not properly set only in iphone x device in ionic3?

Tags: iphone, cordova, ionic3, iphone-x

I have implemented the app in ionic3 in which splash generating issue in the iphone x only but in another iphone devices its working.

> In the Iphone x splash text is cut not properly center aligned.below we have upload the splash issue that is generated in the iphone X device.

**IPhone x Splash**

[image]

**Android device splash screen:**

[image]

Can anyone help me how to fix above issue?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i fixed above issue and follow below procedure for fix:

[image]

Firstly open ur project from Xcode and search below 4 files and open below  github link and replace all the code of every file 1 by one and then run in emulator and check.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/tree/master/src/ios